# Regular expression c# for last 2 digits

Tags: c#, regex

I have  a text box with only numbers, my regex is:

```
^[1-9][0-9][0-9][48,88,51,01]$
```

I want only numbers ending with that 2 digits (`48,88,51,01`) How I can validate this, I'm not good with regular expresions :(

Comment: Try `^[1-9]*[0-9]{2}(?:48|88|51|01)$` - 5 digits number which ends with  `48,88,51,01`

Comment: [regexr.com/76emj](https://regexr.com/76emj) This is a link to Regexr, an interactive playground. I've added the regex and some examples.

Comment: Yes, that works for me, add your comment as a response to mark it as correct

Comment: After giving it more thought, how long are your numbers? Do they specifically have to be 5 digits long? Or are the numbers a variable length?

Comment: @Praxusa Who's answer specifically?

Comment: 6 numbers, the first 4 can be whatever, and the group of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match *6 numbers, the first 4 can be whatever, and the group of 2* using C#, and ending on one of 48, 88, 51, 01 you can make use of a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) but with a different notation.

Then you can make use of a non capture group for the alternatives.

```
^[0-9]{4}(?:[48]8|[50]1)$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/rCqXNA/1).

Or if the first digit should be 1-9:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?:[48]8|[50]1)$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HPJ51R/1).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a non-capturing group `(?:...)` with the `or` operator:

```
^[1-9][0-9][0-9](?:48|88|51|01)$
```

Comment: Typo? It should be `?:` for non-capturing group (nite `:`). Another suggestion is `[0-9]{2}` instead of `[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko IMO this question is fairly vague and OP hasn't really given any indication other than his regex how long each number is/should be.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks, I misremembered.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another approach:

```
\d*(48|88|51|01)$
```

This regular expression first uses the "\d*" pattern to match zero or more digits, then the pipe "|" operator to match either 48, 88, 51, or 01 at the end of the string, indicated by the "$" character.